# Set width of ProgressBar Dynamically Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am using `ProgressBar` dynamically. Now, I want to set its width based on Its Progress.
For i.e. If Its progress is 10% then show its width 10%, If Its progress is 82% then show its width 82%.

**Layout.xml:**

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbAccuracy"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTopic" />
```

I have `RelativeLayout` in xml file.

Comment: I assume that by `Set width of ProgressBar` you mean "set progress indicator"... ?

Comment: So, you just have to initialize the minum (say, 0), maximum (say, 100) once and set the value while processing (an AsyncTask is your best friend, here).

Answer (score 0):

Use solution described http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/

Where

```
 progressBar.setProgress(your start point);
 progressBar.setMax(progress end point);
```

will do the trick for you.